# Compare 2 sets of child nodes to find a match where a least one of the child node values matches one of the other child node values

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have this XML with two sets of table data (element names generalized for simplicity).

```
<root>
    <table>
        <Row type="1">
            <Id>AAAA</Id>
            <Properties>
                <Property>A</Property>
                <Property>D</Property>
            </Properties>
        </Row>
        <Row type="1">
            <Id>BBBB</Id>
            <Properties>
                <Property>B</Property>
            </Properties>
        </Row>
        <Row type="1">
            <Id>CCCC</Id>
            <Properties>
                <Property>G</Property>
                <Property>H</Property>
            </Properties>
        </Row>
    </table>
    <table>
        <Row type="2">
            <Id>123abc</Id>
            <Properties>
                <Property>A</Property>
                <Property>D</Property>
                <Property>E</Property>
            </Properties>
        </Row>
        <Row type="2">
            <Id>456def</Id>
            <Properties>
                <Property>B</Property>
                <Property>C</Property>
                <Property>I</Property>
            </Properties>
        </Row>
        <Row type="2">
            <Id>798ghi</Id>
            <Properties>
                <Property>F</Property>
                <Property>G</Property>
                <Property>H</Property>
            </Properties>
        </Row>
    </table>
</root>
```

I am trying to write a transform to output a new table that associates a row from table 1 to a row in table 2 based on their properties.  Rows in table 1 are not required to have all of the properties present in a row in table 2; any one property is all that's required to be considered a match.  There will always only be a one to one relationship between a row in table 1 and a row in table 2.

My desired output is:

```
<root>
    <Row>
        <Name>NewTable:AAAA</Name>
        <Table2Id>123abc</Table2Id>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Name>NewTable:BBBB</Name>
        <Table2Id>456def</Table2Id>>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Name>NewTable:CCCC</Name>
        <Table2Id>789ghi</Table2Id>
    </Row>
</root>
```

I've started with this and have been trying to follow this logic:  Find me the Id tag of the row in table 2 who has at least one property that matches one of the properties of the current row being processed in table 1.

Here's what I have so far.  It's not working, but I feel like I'm close.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="//Row[@type != '2']">
            <xsl:variable name="Name" select="concat('NewTable:', ./Id)"/>
            <Row>
                <Name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Name"/>
                </Name>
                <Table2Id>
                    <xsl:value-of select="//Row[@type = '2'][Property = ./Property]/Id"/>
                </Table2Id>
            </Row>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that can be very useful here: one is the **key** feature of XSLT that allows you to create a relationship based on matching values. The other is set comparison, where if at least one member of a set matches at least one member of another set, the sets will be considered matching.

Try the following stylesheet that takes advantage of both:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="table2" match="Row[@type=2]" use="Properties/Property" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<root>
    <xsl:for-each select="root/table/Row[@type=1]">
    <row>   
        <Name>
            <xsl:value-of select="Id" />
        </Name>
        <Table2Id>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('table2', Properties/Property)/Id" />
        </Table2Id>
    </row>
    </xsl:for-each>
</root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

BTW, your method would have worked too (albeit less efficiently) if only you had used:

```
[Properties/Property = ./Properties/Property]
```

instead of just:

```
[Property = ./Property]
```

since you are in the context of a `<Row>` (a grandparent of `<Property>`).

Comment: Thanks!  That works as expected.  Appreciate the help.